# Grafbase Collection not displaying if related field deleted

Tags: graphql

I have the following model in my NextJs 13 app. I am using grafbase.

```
// @ts-ignore
const User = g
    .model('User', {
        name: g.string().length({ min: 2, max: 100 
    }).optional(),
    email: g.string().unique(),
    password: g.string().optional(),
    active: g.boolean().optional(),
    allowReset: g.boolean().optional(),
    avatarUrl: g.url().optional(),
})
.auth((rules) => {
    rules.public().read()
    rules.private().create().delete().update()
})

// @ts-ignore
const ActivateToken = g
.model('ActivateToken', {
    token: g.string().unique(),
    activatedAt: g.datetime().optional(),
    createdBy: g.relation(() => User),
})
.auth((rules) => {
    rules.public().read()
    rules.private().create().delete().update()
})
```

After a user is created and activated from an email I send to update the active state everything works fine.

If I delete the ActivateToken, the user no longer shows up in the ActiveTokenCollection, however the user is still in the database as if I search for the user by id it is show. Very strange issue.

If i don't delete the tokens, everything is fine, but thinking about maintenance and not have loads of tokens I thought about deleting older, expired ones.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was purely down to the grafbase package needing to be updated to a new version due to defects in the older version.